# The fixed points of a modulus function/cipher

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let n>1 and left f: N -> N be defined as follows, where a and b are integers.

f(x) = (ax + b) mod n

Then f has no fixed points if and only if gcd(a - 1, n) does not divide b.

How would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ax + b \equiv x \mod n$ means $(1-a) x \equiv b \mod n$.  What are the possible values of $(1-a) x \mod n$?